# Как отключить вывод чекбокса "Предотвратить создание дополнительных диалоговых окон на этой странице"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

В Хроме есть всплывающее окно, вызванное через `window.onbeforeunload = функция`

В этом окне есть чекбокс для предотвращения всплывания этих окон.
Как можно этот чекбокс убрать? На некоторых сайтах видел, что он отсутствует.

Спасибо

Вот пример этого окна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: никак этого не сделать

Answer (score 5):

Никак нельзя. Нечего писать вирусы.

Answer (score 5):

Если вкратце, то **вы не можете этого сделать**.

Теперь развернутое объяснение, которое относится к подобным окнам в целом, не только к конкретно вашему случаю.

По вполне очевидным причинам, связанным с "безопасностью", вы мало что можете сделать, когда пользователь хочет перейти на другую страницу, закрыть вкладку или иным способом покинуть сайт. Дело в том, что браузеры хотят наверняка удостовериться в том, что вы не можете предотвратить закрытие той страницы, которую пользователь решил закрыть.

Именно по этой причине события `beforeunload` (jQuery) и `onbeforeunload` (Vanilla JS) крайне ограничены по функционалу и они точно не предназначены для предотвращения закрытия страниц, за исключением одного стандартного (и скучного) диалогового окна, которое, в зависимости от браузера, может быть не показано.

Некоторые браузеры позволяют изменить сообщение в этом диалоговом окне, а некоторые (например, Firefox) — нет. Причина та же — безопасность. Гипотетически вы можете этим сообщением ввести пользователя в заблуждение, например, выведя такой текст:

> Ваш компьютер взорвется, если вы покинете эту страницу!!!

Насколько мне известно, большинство браузеров все же поддерживает вывод своего текста, но только **в дополнение к стандартному**, которое не может быть изменено. Следует учитывать, что у некоторых браузеров (это не касается десктопных браузеров актуальных версий) `onbeforeunload` вообще отсутствует.

О том, чтобы убрать чекбокс "Предотвратить создание дополнительных диалоговых окон на странице", не может быть и речи, поскольку это еще большее нарушение безопасности. Я не видел ни в одном из известных мне популярных браузеров такой возможности, и, надо признать, слава богу, что не видел.

***p.s.*** *Данный вопрос является частичным переводом этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32018719/2486051) за авторством [Mikk3lRo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3631281/mikk3lro), адаптированного под ваш случай.*