# Расширение Chrome для блокировки диалоговых окон

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Хочу сделать расширение для блокировки диалоговых окон, сделал через manifest.json

```
{
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["js.js"]
```

content.js стандартный:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js.js');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.onload = function() {
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
};
```

а вот js.js:

```
window.alert = function alert(data) {
  console.log('Alert ' + data);
};
Object.defineProperty(window, 'alert', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
});

window.confirm = function confirm(data) {
    console.log('Confirm ' + data);
};
Object.defineProperty(window, 'confirm', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
});

window.prompt = function prompt(data) {
    console.log('prompt' + data);
};
Object.defineProperty(window, 'prompt', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
});
```

на например на сайте https://regex101.com всё-равно выводится диалоговое окно, что я ещё не знаю про браузерный JS?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/489252/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код не работает потому что, он выполняется в контексте `content_scripts` и не имеет доступа к переменным, функциям определенным на странице.

Вот что говорит об этом документация:

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.

Для того, чтобы код начал работать в контексте страницы, нужно определить соответствующий ключ в `manifest.json`, а именно `web_accessible_resources`.

Пример использования этого ключа:

```
{
  "web_accessible_resources": ["js/script.js"]
}
```

где `script.js` - скрипт, который должен выполняться в контексте `web` страницы.

Если встраивать скрипт без указания соответствующего ключа, то в консоли `web` страницы будет получена ошибка:

> Denying load of
>   **chrome-extension://aomgbbmcobgkafcfkedmilgaohcapael/js.js**. Resources
>   must be listed in the **web_accessible_resources** manifest key in order
>   to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

[Execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) | [Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)

**UPD**:

> проблема в том что я спокойно перехватываю все alert/confirm/prompt
>   барузерного JS, но именно на regex101.com всёравно выводится окно, как
>   я понимаю оно другого типа

Это обычное `confirm` окно.

Появляется в результате события `beforeunload`, т.е перед закрытием страницы, но при условие что свойство `returnValue` будет иметь не пустое значение.

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to
>   confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the
>   event is displayed in this dialog.

Кастомизировать его нельзя, из-за политики безопасности. Некоторые версии браузеров (`Firefox` до 44.0, `Google Chrome` до 51.0, и т.д) позволяют изменить текст сообщения. В более новых версиях поддержку кастомных сообщений [удаляют](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility), заменяя на сообщения, которые определяет браузер.

---

В данном случае, при попытке уйти с сайта срабатывает вышеупомянутое событие:

[image: catch beforeunload]

А вот код функции обработчика (часть ревалентного кода не скопирована):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

    var t = {
        regex: $("#regex").val(),
        options: getOptions(),
        regexText: $("#regex_string").val(),
        isSub: sub_enabled(),
        sub: $("#sub").val(),
        delimiter: $("#delimiter_selector").text(),
        flavor: getFlavor(),
        permaid: $("#permalink_menu").attr("data-permalink"),
        unitTests: V(!1)
    }, a = JSON.stringify(t);

    if (a !== X) {
        var i = "Your most recent changes have not been saved. ";
        return i += "If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.", (e || window.event).returnValue = i, i
    }
});
```

Убрать обработчик не получится, так как для для этого нужна ссылка на него, а ее нету, так как применена анонимная функция.

> Calling addEventListener to an anonymous function creates a new
>   listener each time. Calling removeEventListener to an anonymous
>   function has no effect. An anonymous function creates a unique object
>   each time is is called, it is not a reference to an existing object
>   though it may call one. When adding an event listener in this manner
>   be sure it is added only once, it is permanent (can not be removed)
>   untill the object it was added to is destroyed.

[WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) | [Event.returnValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue) | [EventTarget.removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

[Unloading documents](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#prompt-to-unload-a-document)

Comment: Скрипт прописан в web_accessible_resources, без этого он вообще неработает, проблема в том что я спокойно перехватываю все alert/confirm/prompt барузерного JS, но именно на regex101.com всёравно выводится окно, как я понимаю оно другого типа, но как перехватить такие окна я пока-что непонял.

Comment: @vnn198, нужно было указать это сразу, получается нынешний вопрос не корректен. Переформулируйте. О каком окне идет речь? У меня не получилось воспроизвести

Comment: если на сайте regex101.com что-то написать и попытаться закрыть вкладку то вылезет окно "Покинуть эту страницу - возможно изменения не сохранятся" , а без прописывания в "web_accessible_resources" скрипт вообще не сработает и в консоле будет ошибка что это расширение не загружено потому что не прописано в web_accessible_resources, так что я об этом не написал потому что это итак очевидно

Comment: @vnn198, проверьте обновленный ответ.

Comment: Проверю, просто в отпуске сейчас, с интернетом тяжко